# OpenCL kernel produces incorrect image on GPU

Tags: gpu, opencl, gpgpu

I have a OpenCL 1.2 program that converts an equirectangular hdr image to a cubemap.

On my i7-9750H CPU everything works correctly, but when I run the program on my GTX 1650 GPU the result is consistently incorrect.

In case it is relevant, my GPU driver version is 536.99 and 7.6.0.0228 for my CPU.

| Correct | Wrong |
| --- | --- |
| [image: correct cpu result] | [image: incorrect gpu result] |

Here is the code:

```cpp
constant sampler_t srcSampler =
    CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_TRUE | CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE | CLK_FILTER_LINEAR;

// These transforms specify the directions based on the cube face
// They are based on
// https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki_opengl/images/CubeMapAxes.png The order
// is +X, -X, +Y, -Y, +Z, -Z Using the reference image the transforms are
// (horizontal face axis, vertical face axis, face direction)
__constant float3 xTransforms[6] = {
    (float3)(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), (float3)(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f),
    (float3)(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), (float3)(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
    (float3)(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), (float3)(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)};
__constant float3 yTransforms[6] = {
    (float3)(0.0, -1.0f, 0.0f),  (float3)(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f),
    (float3)(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),  (float3)(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f),
    (float3)(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), (float3)(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f)};
__constant float3 zTransforms[6] = {
    (float3)(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), (float3)(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
    (float3)(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),  (float3)(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f),
    (float3)(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),  (float3)(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f)};

float2 projectSphericalMap(float3 dir) {
  float2 uv = (float2)(atan2pi(dir.z, dir.x) * 0.5, asinpi(dir.y));
  uv += (float2)(0.5f, 0.5f);
  return uv;
}

// The kernel is invoked for every pixel on every face of the cubemap
// 'size' is the size of a cube map face
// 'sizefac' is 2/(size-1) precomputed
__kernel void reproject_environment(__read_only image2d_t srcImage,
                                    __write_only image2d_t dstImage, int size,
                                    float sizefac) {
  int outu = get_global_id(0);
  int outv = get_global_id(1);
  int face = get_global_id(2);

  // This check is probably unnecessary
  if (outu >= size || outv >= size || face >= 6) {
    return;
  }

  // The value range is [-1, 1]
  float horizontal = (float)(outu)*sizefac - 1.0;
  float vertical = (float)(outv)*sizefac - 1.0;

  float3 vec = (float3)(horizontal, vertical, 1.0f);

  float x = dot(vec, xTransforms[face]);
  float y = dot(vec, yTransforms[face]);
  float z = dot(vec, zTransforms[face]);

  float3 dir = (float3)(x, y, z);

  float2 uv = projectSphericalMap(normalize(dir));
  float4 color = read_imagef(srcImage, srcSampler, uv);
  // the cube map faces are stacked vertically
  write_imagef(dstImage, (int2)(outu, outv + size * face), color);
}
```

This is my first time using OpenCL so the mistake might be very obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding some `printf`s for debugging I noticed that on my GPU the `float3`s read from the `Transform` arrays were wrong.

The issue is the compiler was aligning the array elements to 4 floats which resulted in a 1 float shift when indexing the elements. Changing `float3` to `float4` fixed the problem.